# Maven projects import does not work well

Tags: eclipse, m2e

This is a weird problem and probably, It has a stupid solution, but still.

I have recently install a windows 32 bit machine on a VBOX (runs originally on linux). I don't know if it is important but maybe.

I installed a fresh eclipse Juno with m2e and m2e-wtp.

I checked out a maven project (multi module) from SVN and then i tried to Import it as maven project to eclipse, simply by right clicking --> import --> maven --> existing maven project.
I have done this millions time with no problems till now.

Eclipse imports all the projects but they all have this error:
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.xx.xx:parent-pom:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM.

Also, when I right click a java project, and check it's properties it seems that eclipse does not recognize it as a java project (I added a screenshot).
[image]

I wish to state that I am the only one here to have this problem, so I assume this is an eclipse problem.

Please help.

Regards,
Idob

Comment: and you are positive to have the parent pom one step up the hierarchy? Can you build it with maven from command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure, that the parent-pom is available in the correct version?
The error message tells you that the parent-pom is not available.
Either it has to be available as an eclipse project, or it has to be available at your repository. You can find your local repository in WinXP machine by default at Documents and Settings\.m2\repository.